# What is the correct way to use component props in a Vuex getter?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Assume you have a simple app component with a button to add multiple counters from a counter component using a vuex store.

[Here is the whole thing on webpackbin.](http://www.webpackbin.com/NkgzMe8Db)

A bit like the basic counter example from the [vuex git repo](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/tree/master/examples/counter).But you want to use the vuex getter with an ID that is handed over via a property on the component, how would you do that?

The getter has to be a pure function, so you can't use `this.counterId`. The official docs say you have to use a computed property, but that doesn't seem to work either. This code returns undefined for the getter:

```
import * as actions from './actions'

export default {
    props: ['counterId'],
    vuex: {
        getters: {
            count: state => state.counters[getId]
        },
        actions: actions
    },
    computed: {
        getId() { return this.counterId }
    },
}
```

Comment: your code seems to be right. The idea behind the "getId" computed property is for you to use properties from your Component, instead from your State. In your case, you are doing both. Nothing wrong with it, but pay attention to your logic when calling getId() and what are you getting from it.

Comment: the id is just the array index. the computed property itself works fine. tho the getter still returns undefined so there must be something wrong. I am using the computed property because you can't use `this` in the getter by definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

getters should be pure functions and not dependent on component state.

you can still crate a computed prop from the getter, or directly use the store:

```
//option A
export default {
    props: ['counterId'],
    vuex: {
        getters: {
            counters: state => state.counters
        },
        actions: actions
    },
    computed: {
        currentCounter() { return this.counters[this.counterId] }
    },
}

//option B (better suited for this simple scenario)
import store from '../store'
computed: {
  currentCounter() {  
    return store.state.counters[this.counterId] 
  }
}
```

Comment: Added both versions on webpackbin
[Version A](http://www.webpackbin.com/NkgzMe8Db) - [Version B](http://www.webpackbin.com/NyXxnxUPW)
Generally it works, but the mutations dont update the counter. I can increment the counter a few times and it only gets updated when use the AddCounter function to add a new one.

Comment: That was a problem of your mutations. you incremented the values with `state.counter[counterId]++` which Vue could not detect (http://vuejs.org/guide/list.html#Caveats). I used .splice() instead and it works: http://www.webpackbin.com/Vy_BMMIwZ (also changed the Couter.vue to receive the counter)

Comment: Alright, got it, you were right. I forgot to use state.counters.$set(counterId, state.counters[counterId] + 1) instead of the ++ in the store objects mutations ...